# Fix substitution of “shell_cmd” on Mac OSX in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-anaconda

I have a problem with my build system specified in project settings. Currently my project settings look like this

```
{
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
            "name": "Anaconda Python Builder",
            "selector": "source.python",
            "shell_cmd": "$project_path/bin/python -u $file"
        }
    ],
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "file_exclude_patterns":
            [
                "pip-selfcheck.json",
                "pyvenv.cfg"
            ],
            "folder_exclude_patterns":
            [
                "lib",
                "include",
                "bin"
            ],
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "binary_file_patterns":
        [
            "*.jpg",
            "*.jpeg",
            "*.png",
            "*.gif",
            "*.ttf",
            "*.tga",
            "*.dds",
            "*.ico",
            "*.eot",
            "*.pdf",
            "*.swf",
            "*.jar",
            "*.zip",
            "client/node_modules/**",
            "data/**"
        ]
    }
}
```

The actual problem problem is in the line:

```
"shell_cmd": "$project_path/bin/python -u $file"
```

Every time I close sublime and reopen it my `shell_cmd` gets substituted with this

```
"shell_cmd": "\"python\" -u \"$file\""
```

Which fails my build. Is there a way to fix this problem? What do I do to disable this automatic substitution?

- Mac OS X 10.11.3
- Sublime Text 3103

Comment: Silly question, but I assume you're saving your project (`⌘-S`) before closing Sublime?

Comment: @MattDMo yes, that's right. I just checked again and substitution happens when I open sublime actually.

Comment: I'd suggest [opening an issue](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/issues) on Github. In my experience the package's author is pretty responsive, and new versions are pushed out all the time, so this may just be a regression. Before you open the issue, though, make sure you're running the latest version by using the `Package Control: Upgrade Package` option in the Command Palette.

Comment: @MattDMo do you think it's related to package? Not sublime itself?

Comment: Yes, I think it's definitely related to the package. Sublime should not be editing project files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already answered this question in the Anaconda's issues tracker but I will do it here for any other user that lands in this question with a similar problem.

That specific build system is used by Anaconda itself and that is why it is called "Anaconda Python Builder", it will update the "shell_cmd" with anything that you used as configuration for your "python_interpreter" setting into your anaconda's settings file (general, user or per project).

If you have specific needs for your build system, you should create a new build entry with your own options and stick to that one. Anaconda's build system is a convenience for users that need to use their configured Python interpreter instead of the embedded ST3 one.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue without a custom build system by adding `python_interpreter: 'full/path/to/python'` to the settings dictionary. python part in the Anaconda Python Builder `shell_cmd` gets replaced with it.